# Look at data in one date range and count from another date range

Tags: sql-server, date-range, having

I'm stuck on a query where I am trying to get information on just customers that are newly acquired during a certain date range.

I had need to get a list of customers who placed their first order (of all time) in the first 6 months of the year. I then need to get total of their invoices, first invoice date, last invoice date, and count of orders for just the last 6 months.

I used a HAVING clause to ensure that I am just looking at customers that placed their first order in that 6 month period, but since we are past that period now, the total invoice info and order count information would include orders placed after this time.  I considered including a restriction in the HAVING clause for the 'last invoice date', but then I am eliminating customers whose first order date was in the 6 month block, but also ordered after that. I'm not sure what to do next and am not having luck finding similar questions.  Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT c.customer, MAX(c.name) AS Name, 
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN im.debit = 0
        THEN im.amount * -1
        ELSE im.amount
        END
    ) AS TotalInvoiceAmount,
    MIN(
          im.date) AS FirstInvoiceDate,
    MAX(
        im.date) AS LastInvoiceDate,
    COUNT(DISTINCT om.[order]) AS OrderCount
FROM invoicem im
INNER JOIN customer c ON im.customer = c.customer
FULL JOIN orderm om ON im.customer = om.customer
WHERE im.amount <> 0
GROUP BY c.customer
HAVING MIN(im.date) BETWEEN '01-01-2015' AND '06-30-2015'
ORDER BY c.customer
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the first 6 months qualification as a subquery. This would also work as a CTE

```
declare @startDate date = dateadd(month,-6,getdate())

SELECT c.customer, MAX(c.name) AS Name, 
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN im.debit = 0
        THEN im.amount * -1
        ELSE im.amount
        END
    ) AS TotalInvoiceAmount,
    MIN(
          im.date) AS FirstInvoiceDate,
    MAX(
        im.date) AS LastInvoiceDate,
    COUNT(DISTINCT om.[order]) AS OrderCount
FROM invoice im
INNER JOIN (SELECT customer from invoice
            GROUP BY customer
            HAVING MIN(date) BETWEEN '01-01-2015'
            AND '06-30-2015') im2
ON im.customer = im2.customer
INNER JOIN customer c ON im.customer = c.customer
FULL JOIN orderm om ON im.customer = om.customer
WHERE im.amount <> 0
AND im.date >= @startdate
GROUP BY c.customer
ORDER BY c.customer
```

Comment: Thanks!  I am getting errors with this though, it states that:   Column 'invoicem.customer' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
And
The multi-part identifier "c.customer" could not be bound

Comment: @DisplayBee that is referring to your subquery. See Edits

Comment: thanks. I still get the c.customer issue.  I don't get why it doesn't recognize that, but I am still trying to learn!

Comment: Thanks!  You are a lifesaver!  And I get it now.  :)

Comment: @DisplayBee If this answer works for you, you should select it as correct

Comment: Sorry, I didn't initially see the "correct" option.  I thought this worked for me, but it actually isn't.  What happens is that the "OrderCount" I am getting is actually returning the count for the entire lifetime of the customer still. I'll update this when I get it to work.